# A word for first name and middle name/s, but not last name

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to denote both first name and middle name/s, but not the last name?

That is, when we speak about J.R.R. Tolkien, we may say that *Tolkien* is a surname, and *John Ronald Reuel* is [the requested word]

(*John* is a first name; *Ronald* and *Reuel* are middle names).

Comment: This is going to vary a lot between cultures but I'd say "given names" for the first and middle and "family name/surname" for the last (at least where I live).

Comment: Ya' know...there are a lot of of us hi-rep users offering "real" answers, and only one up-vote for the Q. C'mon....if a question is worth answering, it is worth an upvote.

Comment: @Cascabel IKR! You'd think it would be common courtesy to upvote a question you answer, or upvote any answer to your question (unless you're in a strange situation wre you feel like you must answer a poor question, or the answer is just not good enough for your question.).

Comment: @Mitch Granted SE votes are as meaningless as "reputation" on EBay, but unlike EBay there is no compulsion to upvote every "transaction". The pop-up over the upvote arrow says "This question shows research effort, is useful and clear". I would score that as 0 for research, maybe 1/2 for useful, and 1 for clear. That's average, at best. Not worth an upvote IMO.

Comment: I have to concur with alephzero, except I would rate this question as 0 for research, 0 for usefulness, and 1 for clear. Not worth an upvote.

Comment: I think that votes should be voted just fair: otherwise, it would gradually lead to vote inflation. In this particular case, I think the question should have lesser number of votes, maybe 2, 3, or 5; not 16. I'm just a random guy from Russia and I don't try to teach there anyone, but I think this discussion about votes is completely off-topic.

Comment: The difference between first and middle names exists only in the mind of some people - you are free to change them around and go by your former middle name as your new first name. They are all the same class, and one of them is chosen by your parents to be the 'daily-use' one.

Comment: Reuel wasn't one of Tolkein's forenames, it was a family name. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/247600/116908

Comment: @Aganju Absolutely...it is common practice in many cultures to take the 'middle' name as the 'friend ' name.

Comment: @alephzero  I only ask that those who have taken the time to provide an answer to also provide an up-vote to the question  out of common courtesy. Others might find this question very helpful, even though it lacks  research.  It has 4K views in only 2 days.

Comment: Forename. This word is used far less frequently in English than its three-syllable German counterpart "Vorname" (in which the "v" is pronounced exactly like an "f" in English—something that Charles, Prince of Wales seems not to fully grasp but that his father Prince Philip knew well), but it makes sense and I expect that its use in writing will be understood by literate persons who know English. But in speaking if you mention someone's "forenames", you might be thought to have said "four names." (BTW, the third syllable of "Vorname" is a schwa.)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

***given names***

> the name that is chosen for you at birth and is not your family name:
>
> - Ex. Her family name is Smith and her given names are Mary Elizabeth.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/given-name)

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/given%20name) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given_name) tend to agree.

Comment: Some people add further 'middle names' at say confirmation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't thought about that...although I have  stood as godfather to a few kids here it never occurred to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That would also be true of people who have changed their names by deed poll. I knew someone who had the same given name initial as his father and inserted another given/personal/chosen/Christian name by deed poll just to stop them opening each other's post.

Comment: @BoldBen One wonders how the question here is complicated by people having middle (or initial) letters rather than names. Harry S. Truman, Michael J. Fox,  Ulysses S. Grant, Joanne K. Rowling .... (I'm not sure if they liked/like the periods or not).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - there is a story, possibly apocryphal, about an American called RB Jones, where the R and B stood for nothing but themselves, and was called 'Arbee Jones' by the IRS. He wrote an angry letter of correction saying 'My name is R (only) B (only) Jones' and started getting letters to Ronly Bonly Jones.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - *Possibly* apocryphal? (-: Heard it from my old army sergeant <mumble> years ago. We did have in my unit a man with no middle name or initial. Of course this had to be reconciled with army forms and so for a brief time he became (say) George Nmi Jones.

Comment: *Given names* does not quite work in Russian where, for example with Ivan Ivanovich Ivanov who has a given name of Ivan and a family name of Ivanov, plus a patronymic of Ivanovich (son of Ivan), the patronymic is automatic rather than given but is not the  family name

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Rowling's personal name is Joanne Rowling. Her pen-name is J.K. Rowling (since apparently her publishers didn't want her pen-name to be obviously female, for marketing reasons, and preferred two initials). "Joanne K Rowling" is a malapropism.

Comment: @Henry: *Given names* does not have to work in Russian. We are in an English Language forum. Perhaps you meant to say "Russian names"? However, in spite of the fact that I know many Russian emigres and 1st gen, I've never heard one of them use the old patronymic fashion for names. AMOF, when I was working in Russia, I don't recall hearing the patronymic used. I have to wonder if the Soviets wiped out that fashion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think the use of a single letter as a name is not an issue at all. I've worked with a man whose given **first name** is H. Just H, nothing more, and that is how we referred to him.

Comment: @BoldBen: I have to wonder that no one has yet answered the (until recently) most common way to label the given names, as *Christian names*.

Comment: @MarkGB The difficulty with _Christian names_ is that it isn't universal and can't be used on forms and web pages for that reason. Imagine asking the former Cat Stevens for his 'Christian Name' when he's been Yusuf Islam for decades. Even _forename(s)_ can be problematic, In some cultures (Chinese for example) the family name comes first. XI Jinping is Comrade Xi not Comrade Jinping.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is a similar story about the mathematician [R._H._Bing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._H._Bing) who [received a visa made out to "Ronly Honly Bing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._H._Bing#What_does_R._H._stand_for?).

Comment: @BoldBen: we are in total agreement that "Christian name", or even forename, is problematic on many levels, and in various naming conventions. But we are only addressing the topic as regards common usage in English.

Comment: @JimMack I have no doubts about that 'apocryphal' story. The military is often quite intransigent on such matters. I had a situation back during my induction into the USN in the 70s, and tried to explain my religious beliefs of the time to a rather snotty E2. He finally gave up trying to classify me and had "Other' listed on my dog-tags in the religion spot. A similar story came up once from across the pond when a drill sergeant was trying to separate new recruits for Sunday worship..."C of E on the left, Catholics on the right, and "fancy buggers" in the middle..."

Answer (score 31):

You might say ***forenames*** for first and middle names

> **forename** - A person's first or ‘Christian’ name (OED)

Comment: I think this is the traditional answer.  (Though of course it might be a bit parochial, failing for cultures where the family name(s) come first.)

Comment: Yes @gidds, perhaps in those cases there is an equivalent '*after*name' ?

Comment: Someone on the phone asked me what my forenames were, and I said I didn't have that many...

Comment: @Dan In Dutch, people use "voornaam" ('before name') and "achternaam" ('after name') for given name and family name.

Answer (score 13):

In my lifetime, the two most common words used to describe names other than the family name are *given* names and *Christian* names. The latter has been steadily falling out of favor. Indeed, a google ngram view of the two shows exactly that phenomenon: [n-gram of *christian name*, *given name*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=christian%20name%2C%20given%20name&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0). Although, it should be noted, in common usage both labels are applied to mean the first name, or commonly used name (should it be other than the first) only. There is no single word, in English, that will **automatically** be understood by the recipient of a communication (verbal or written) to mean "all the names a person has not including their family name".

(Edit: for an interesting comparison, add *forename* to that n-gram view.)

Comment: Where do you live? I am quite surprised that in your lifetime the term "Christian names" was common. I assume you must live in a very christian part of the world, right? As your NGram shows, "christian name" has been steadily disappearing for more than 100 years. I would certainly never use it and would find it very jarring (borderline offensive, as would be other, similar expressions such as "speak Christian" or "christendom" to mean "world").

Comment: @terdon - I'm in the US, and you have to realize I am in my 7th decade. I agree that today many people would find "Christian name" jarring, at the least. Even so for the past 20-30 years, unless you are among the many amongst the evangelical and "born-again" persuasions. As for "very Christian" describing the US, I defer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_in_the_United_States

Comment: Yes, the US would certainly qualify as very Christian, no argument there, that would explain it. I am still surprised that the expression was common at some point in the last 70 years or so. I don't doubt you for a second, I am sure you're right, it's just not something I (in my 4th decade, all of which I've spent in various countries in Europe) have ever come across outside novels, so I thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon I remember "Christian name" being quite common in the UK, and I am nowhere near 70. Indeed, switching that ngram to "British English" paints quite a different picture.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime so it does. Interesting, thanks!

Comment: The British English ngram - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=christian+name%2Cgiven+name%2Cforename%2Cforenames&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforename%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforenames%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforename%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforenames%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Wow! The ngram changes dramatically when it's made case-insensitive... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=christian+name%2Cgiven+name%2Cforename%2Cforenames&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

Comment: When I worked in Saudi Arabia some 30 years ago, we always stayed alert for the unbearable solecism in which that one of the Westerners asked one of the locals: "What's your Christian name?" Everybody did it at least once. It never got old.

Comment: @terdon Native Brit here, 6 decades in. The term "Christian name" was the most common word we had for a given name when I was a child. As far as I'm aware, it's still common, despite the perceived non-inclusive nature of it.

Comment: @MarkGB ...just read your SE bio...that sounds like a fascinating job. But what the heck is "pest" wild geese? Is that like migrating geese looking for a new spawning ground intruding on human built-up areas?

Comment: @Cascabel, kinda OT, but no way to PM, eh? Canada geese become pests from 2 sources. One: migrating geese who stop migrating, since food is plentiful. Two: former live decoy Canada geese, ancestors originally raised in captivity as (duh) live decoys. Released into the wild decades (and generations) ago, when live decoys became illegal, they don't know how to migrate.  A single adult goose defecates on the order of 2-3 lbs of poop per day. Bad news for lawns, beaches, playing fields. We teach them they should find somewhere else.

Comment: @PrimeMover: How common was it for people to answer “What's your Christian name?” with “I don't have one; I'm a Muslim”?

Comment: @Dan When I was a child, I never knew it ever happened. I probably did it myself when I was a child, of my Asian classmates. The very concept of a different religion was alien to me in those days and I wouldn't even have known what a Muslim was. In the Saudi situation it didn't happen because *they* were the ones with the difficulty in accepting the existence of other religions apart from knowing they were out there, somewhere.

Answer (score 12):

Try [personal names](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personal%20name)

> : a name (as the praenomen or the forename) by which an individual is intimately known or designated and which may be displaced or supplemented by a surname, a cognomen, or a royal name

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personal%20name)

Comment: I tried to re-format to improve aspect and presentation... if you are not happy you can always roll back...

Comment: It's fine, thanks

Answer (score -8):

***Full name***

> [The Full Names of Everyone in the Royal Family](https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/life/a20083318/prince-george-full-name-royals/)
> King George VI, born **Albert Frederick Arthur George** (1895-1952)
> Queen Elizabeth II, born **Elizabeth Alexandra Mary** (1926-)

Now some might opine that **full name** suggests also a person's family/last name (surname) and it's a possibility, especially since middle names are becoming less frequent.  Therefore, the clearest and simplest phrase is to say: **first and middle names**.

Comment: ...interesting read, and very appropriate at this moment in the history of the Windor Royals.

Comment: Some ... Lexico, Collins, Wiktionary and Macmillan, for instance. That is a non-conventional usage; the royal family of course are rarely referred to using surnames.

Comment: So 'full name' is not the same as your 'name in full'?

Comment: Just checking with OED which has 'full name' as "*a person's whole name, including his or her first name and surname, and often any middle names*".

Comment: I don't think this is correct - "full name" specifically includes *all* parts of the name, including the surname.

Comment: This is definitely not what was asked for. The term "full name" unambiguously includes a person's surname, but the question asked for a term which excludes a person's surname.

Comment: You can call it opining if you wish, but "Full Name" certainly includes the surname.

Comment: I was wrong. I was mistaken.

Comment: Further to this, the Royal family is not a great choice for exemplifying name usage, because they don't use surnames in the common way non-Royals do. Nuns and  monks would be another special-case group.

Comment: Windsor is the "adopted" surname.In 1917 for historical and political reasons "the house of Saxe-Coburg-Gotha" was felt to be too German for British royalty.